# Linkerd error | 2.13.1 | policy container throwing error "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: azure-aks, linkerd

linkerd-destination pod is going to Crashloop when I checked the log so found that policy container not starting and could see below logs . I have tried to install Linkerd version `2.11.* ,2.12.*` and `2.13.1` .
I was getting same error in all version. please find the below error.

```
"2023-04-28T09:52:16.495820Z ERROR kube_client::client::builder: failed with error error trying to connect: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)
Error: failed to get lease: HyperError: error trying to connect: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)

Caused by:
    0: HyperError: error trying to connect: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)
    1: error trying to connect: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)
    2: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)
    3: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)
    4: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)
"
```

Note: this error I am getting on the cluster which is behind the firewall. we have whitelisted kubernetes api server in the firewall. not able to figure out why policy container is not working.
But if same version I am trying on the without firewall clusters so its all pods running .

Just want to understand is something require to whitelist in firewall for policy container?  and how to fix issue ?

Same code is working in without firewall cluster and not working with firewall .

Current Environment:
`AKS version: 1.24.10 Linkerd: 2.13.1`